# Workaround for nested while->fetch

Tags: php, mysqli

Good day everyone!

Currently I'm trying to find a workaround for my problem. As fair as I am concerned, MySqli doesnt support nested fetch'es, therefore my function doesn't quite work. I've tried to find a fix, but had no luck. My current code:

```
function viewQuestionnaire($id){

    $questionStmt = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT id, type, name FROM TAP_questions WHERE questionnaire_id=?;");
    $questionStmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $questionStmt->bind_result($id, $type, $name);
    $questionStmt->execute();
    $result = array();

    while ($questionStmt->fetch()) {
        $questions = new StdClass();
        $questions->question_id = $id;
        $questions->question_type = $type;
        $questions->question_options = array();
        $questions->question_name = $name;
        if($questions->question_type=="2"){
            $stmtOptions= $this->connection->prepare("SELECT id, options FROM TAP_options WHERE question_id=?;");
            $stmtOptions->bind_param("i", $id);
            $stmtOptions->bind_result($qu_id, $qu_opt);
            $stmtOptions->execute();
            while ($stmtOptions->fetch()) {
                $options = new StdClass();
                $options->option_id = $qu_id;
                $options->option_name = $qu_opt;
                array_push($questions->question_options, $options);
            }

            $stmtOptions->close();
        }

        array_push($result, $questions);
    }

    $questionStmt->close();


    return $result;
}
```

As you can see, i'm trying to grab values from database, depending on the question type. If the question type is "2", i need to grab "additional" values from another table. How do i do that?

Vlad

Comment: There is no limitation for doing (nested) fetches.

Comment: You can't have two simultaneous queries because mysqli uses unbuffered queries by default (for prepared statements; it's the opposite for vanilla mysql_query).

Comment: but you can tell to use buffered queries, that should be control-able.

Comment: i've updated my initial post with my original code, could you help me or give a hint how to fix the issue?

Comment: Sorry for being that unclear, you can store the result to buffer it, that is one more method call to do for the outer result: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php

Answer (score 0):

I had more or less exactly this problem two weeks ago and found two working solutions:

1.) Nesting the queries, but using/initializing two different connections for them (even if it's to the same database)

2.) Doing one query first, saving the result in an array and using that array later inside the other query.

Comment: You don't need to create an array your own, you can just tell the driver to buffer the result: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php

Comment: yes, that's basically what I meant (I didn't mean "create an array to save the data" but "use the php function to save the result it in an array"...)

Answer (score 0):

If you buffer the result, you can run the second query w/o loosing the result from the first query.

In Mysqli you buffer the result of an executed prepared statement (which by default is unbuffered) via the [`mysqli_stmt::store_result` method](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php).

```
...

$questionStmt = $connection->prepare(
    "SELECT id, type, name FROM TAP_questions WHERE questionnaire_id=?;"
);
$questionStmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$questionStmt->bind_result($id, $type, $name);
$questionStmt->execute();

/* store result */
$questionStmt->store_result();

...

/* free result */
$questionStmt->free_result();

$questionStmt->close();

...
```